# Equation: $\sqrt[4]{3(x+5)}-\sqrt[4]{x+13}=\sqrt[4]{11-x}-\sqrt[4]{3(3-x)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt[4]{3(x+5)}-\sqrt[4]{x+13}=\sqrt[4]{11-x}-\sqrt[4]{3(3-x)}$

Could someone help me solve this ?

Comment: There is a fairly obvious trivial solution when $x=-1$. Of course, you probably want to find all the solutions..

Comment: Could you show your solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=y-1$, then we have
$$\sqrt[4]{12-3y}+\sqrt[4]{12+3y}=\sqrt[4]{12-y}+\sqrt[4]{12+y}$$
Observe that if $a^4+b^4=2c$ constant, using then $a^4-b^4=2d>0$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial d}(\sqrt[4]{c-d}+\sqrt[4]{c+d})=\frac{(c-d)^{3/4}-(c+d)^{3/4}}{4 (c-d)^{3/4} (c+d)^{3/4}}$$
Is a strictly decreasing function in $d$ on $(0,c)$, so equality can only hold if $y=3y\Rightarrow x=-1$.

Comment: Please tell me why d>0 ?

Comment: Without loss of generality (as the expression is symmetric in $a$ and $b$ and is without any former constraints), we can assume that $a\geq b$.